# How to retain Object passing to a block in ARC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, block

I have this code which I have some tasks I want to do it parallel, the problem is a movie object is release on each run loop before dispatch can process it. Is there a way to retain this in ARC ? Now I process most of logic out side the dispatch and pass it in with __block, but if it is a time consuming process and want to process it in the dispatch block what should I do ?

```
for (HTMLNode *movie in movieContainer) {
  dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
// time consuming process on movie object
});

dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
   // combine the results
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time, you don't have to. Blocks automatically capture all variables that are used by default, however, when using fast iteration, there is an exception.

Because  fast iteration uses `__unsafe_unretained` raw pointers instead of strong ones (for speed), you can simply qualify your iteration variable with strong in this scenario:

```
for (HTMLNode __strong *movie in movieContainer) {
  dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
// time consuming process on movie object
});
```

Comment: It turn out that HTMLNode isn't nil, but it children does. I'm using https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser do you have some idea what may go wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

create a local variable with the keyword `__strong` and affect it the movie object. Then use this strong local variable in your dispatch_async call.

Answer (score -1):

manual retain release

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
id objc_retain(id);
void objc_release(id);

objc_retain(object);
objc_release(object);
```

or

variable with

```
__strong
```

Comment: A very bad idea. NEVER use `objc_retain`. It will send ARC into a hell hole, as it doesn't expect you to do stuff like this.

Comment: there are situations when no other options, but there __strong is better

Comment: there are ALWAYS better options. Even if it involves a temporary strong object, you should NEVER try to take reference counting into your hands when using ARC (and not using CFObjects).